# Image layout transition without pipeline stage dependency

Tags: vulkan

I would like to load an image asynchronously, and while the image is loading I would show a place holder image that is already loaded to the GPU.

The idea would be to have a fence, which I can query to know if the image is ready for rendering. This fence is obtained when submitting to the queue.

```
if(fenceIsSignaled)
    // draw using the intended image
else
    // draw using a placeholder image
```

I use a staging buffer to fill the first mip data.

I attempted recording this into a cmd buffer:

- Transition the image from LAYOUT_UNDEFINED to LAYOUT_TRANSFER_DST_OPTIMAL using a barrier with:

```cpp
const VkImageMemoryBarrier imgBarrier = {
    .sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_IMAGE_MEMORY_BARRIER,
    .srcAccessMask = VK_ACCESS_NONE,
    .dstAccessMask = VK_ACCESS_TRANSFER_WRITE_BIT,
    .oldLayout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_UNDEFINED,
    .newLayout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_TRANSFER_DST_OPTIMAL,
    .image = imgVk,
    .subresourceRange = {
        .aspectMask = VK_IMAGE_ASPECT_COLOR_BIT,
        .baseMipLevel = 0,
        .levelCount = img.mipLevels,
        .baseArrayLayer = 0,
        .layerCount = 1,
    }
};
vkCmdPipelineBarrier(cmdBuffer,
    VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_HOST_BIT, VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_TRANSFER_BIT,
    0, // VkDependencyFlagBits
    0, nullptr,
    0, nullptr,
    1, &imgBarrier);
```

- Copy from the staging buffer to the image with: `vkCmdCopyBufferToImage`
- Then I do some `vkCmdBlitImage` to generate the mipmap chain together with some more barriers.
- Finally I need to transition the whole image from `TRANSFER_DST_OPTIMAL` or `TRANSFER_SRC_OPTIMAL` to `SHADER_READ_ONLY_OPTIMAL` so it can be sampled in the fragment shader. THIS IS THE STEP I'M HAVING TROUBLE WITH.

I need a barrier such as this:

```cpp
vkCmdPipelineBarrier(cmdBuffer, VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_TRANSFER_BIT,
    uploadMode == UploadMode::ASYNC ? VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_BOTTOM_OF_PIPE_BIT : VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_FRAGMENT_SHADER_BIT,
    0,
    0, nullptr,
    0, nullptr,
    std::size(imgBarriers) - firstBarrierIsEmpty,
    imgBarriers + firstBarrierIsEmpty);
```

The thing is: I wanted to use `STAGE_BOTTOM_OF_PIPE` for `dstStageMask` so, in theory, that wouldn't introduce a pipeline dependency; if I use `STAGE_FRAGMENT_SHADER`, the pipeline will wait in the fragment shader stage until the image is ready. But I don't want that, I want to keep rendering frames in the meanwhile.

The problem is that the validation layers tell me that that kind of layout transition is not compatible with the dstStageMask.

```cpp
VUID-vkCmdPipelineBarrier-dstAccessMask-02816(ERROR / SPEC):
msgNum: 1774732925 - Validation Error: [ VUID-vkCmdPipelineBarrier-dstAccessMask-02816 ]
Object 0: handle = 0x253d375a5f0, type = VK_OBJECT_TYPE_COMMAND_BUFFER; |
MessageID = 0x69c8467d |
vkCmdPipelineBarrier(): .pImageMemoryBarriers[0].dstAccessMask bit
VK_ACCESS_SHADER_READ_BIT is not supported by stage mask (VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_BOTTOM_OF_PIPE_BIT).
The Vulkan spec states: The dstAccessMask member of each element of pMemoryBarriers must
only include access flags that are supported by one or more of the pipeline stages in dstStageMask,
as specified in the table of supported access types (https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.3-extensions/html/vkspec.html#VUID-vkCmdPipelineBarrier-dstAccessMask-02816)
```

How would you implement the desired behavior with that limitation?

Comment: "*But I don't want that, I want to keep rendering frames in the meanwhile.*" This statement represents a huge amount of confusion. The barrier in question is, presumably, executing on some other queue, along with the transfer operation, right? Because if it isn't, then you're not *really* doing anything asynchronously.

Comment: Indeed, your talk of using a fence strongly suggests that the submission that's doing the transfer and the rendering submissions aren't the same. That's why your fence check exists, right? So... why exactly are you concerned about the pipeline barrier?

Comment: @Nicol Bolas I'm using the same queue actually. I didn't know I should use two queues, for it to be asynchronous. I though I could do it asynchronously,  using a single queue, if I didn't introduce data dependencies that prevents it from running asynchronously. Hence my concern about that specific pipeline barrier. But maybe this approach is just wrong...

Comment: Queues are not smart. Barriers exist *because* queues aren't that smart. But just as you cannot presume everything in a queue executes in submission order, you cannot presume that everything executes out of order in the most favorable/performant way possible. Queues are not going to scan through the waiting commands to find something to work on if there's some unused hardware. They are going to generally work on stuff in the order you submitted them.